# Code to make a post sticky

Tags: posts, sticky-post, post-meta

How is it possible to upgrade a post to make it sticky directly from code, not by admin area?
Is it possible through a code like:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);
```

In this case, the $post_id is known, but the $meta_key?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sticky posts are saved as an array of post IDs in the *wp_options* table. Hence,

```
$stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$stickies[] = $post_id;
update_option( 'sticky_posts', $stickies );
```

will make the post in question sticky.

**EDIT:**

Even better, the core provides functions to stick and unstick posts (had to have 'em).

```
stick_post( $post_id );
unstick_post( $post_id );
```

--> See [source on trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L1798)