# Update a post to remove sticky option

Tags: sticky-post

I'm working on a plugin that we'll remove posts from the 'sticky posts'.
I'll use the post ID to find it. What function should i use to remove the sticky option after i get this post?
Something like this:

`update_post($id, 'sticky', false);`

(i know the above example won't work...)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was simple...

```
unstick_post( $post_id );
```

Thanks to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54052/65424